# How to Center text based on subset of text?

Tags: html, css

I have a heading and then a subscript using HTML.

```
<h1>
    $250
    <sub>
    5%
    </sub>
</h1>
```

The problem is I want to center this heading based on the $250 not including the 5% in a div. So if I use center it counts the entire width not just the width excluding the sub. I would like to avoid using absolute positioning if possible.

Comment: Where should the 5% appear?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is any straightforward way to do this due to how centering is calculated.  What you can do is use `position: absolute` on the `<sub>` so it is out of the centering flow and doesn't affect centering.  The problem there is that it is also not affected by the `vertical-align: sub`, so you more or less have to create that effect on your own via positioning properties such as `bottom` or working with the margins.

http://jsfiddle.net/7jh5W/